# React native can't debug while adding .aar file

Tags: android, react-native, androidx, aar

I have a React Native ("react-native": "0.62.2", with androidx enabled) project with a simple Android Library .aar. All works fine in debug mode and release mode.

While adding a new .aar file to my React Native project, then the application can't be run in debug mode. I get this Logcat on Android studio

```
2020-05-15 09:30:02.389 15732-15854/com.awesomeproject E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:235)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:259)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1243)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1000(ReactInstanceManager.java:132)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:996)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

On device, I get the corresponding message `Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.`

However, in release mode

> npx react-native run-android --variant=release

the application runs correctly without issues.

Also, the new .aar file works normally when integrated to a native Android application. This .aar contains java code and c++11, thus JNI is used and the NDK of android_sdk also.

Any Ideas?

Comment: run this command on the root of your project.
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Comment: @Waheed Akhtar Thank you. This command disables debugging JS and automatic refresh. It allows only debugging java code using Android Studio.

Comment: Hi ssn, Have you find the solution for your issue. I meet the same as you